# Pycharm unresolved references with Django

Tags: django, pycharm

This is my 5th day learning Django. I've got a Django project working in a virtual environment using Pycharm. The problem I have is, Pycharm can't reference certain imports when they are actually working in Django without any issues. I've selected the right interpretor for the project but Pycharm cannot connect the imports with the .py files in the Django project. The selected interpretor does have Django for the virtual environment but it still doesn't work. Below are the screenshots:
[import works in Django but Pycharm cannot resolve reference with the correct interpretor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ra0.jpg)

Comment: Did you "Enable Django Support"? Languages & Frameworks > Django > "Enable Django Support".

Comment: @Jarad Thanks for replying. This is what I get: https://ibb.co/vjzDnJv. Just to let you know, I am using the Community Edition and not the Professional edition.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't consider your PyCharm version.  I think I know the issue. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the project's root source. You can do this by right-clicking:

[image: mark as sources root]

Or by going to PyCharm settings > Project: Project Structure > and make sure to mark the project root directory (the folder that holds your project's apps) as a "Sources" directory.

[image: PyCharm settings]

**Sidenote**: I noticed you're not using directory-level urls.py. I would suggest doing that instead of trying to import URLs from other apps into the project-level urls.py.

What this means is, each app - articles, accounts, etc. - would have a file named "urls.py".

In your project-level urls.py, you do this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

In your app-level urls.py, you do this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import my_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', my_view, name="hey"),
]
```

Comment: I marked the outer "MyDjango" directory as Sources Root and it worked. It no longer shows the errors. There is another "MyDjango" directory inside the one I marked. I found there is only one "urls.py" in the inner "MyDjango" directory. The other app directories don't have their own "url.py" files. While your answer helped, just thought to let you know. Image: https://ibb.co/CHWqjtZ

Comment: Correct. You'd have to make the app-level `urls.py` manually. Just letting you know about a best-practice. Glad your issue is resolved.